# How to Find Missing Value Between Two Mysql Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
select userid from cw_users where NOT EXISTS(Select userid from cw_users_data)
```

The previous query won't do the job of course.

Trying to find only a missing 'userid' from tableb by doing a comparison.

Both tables contain 'userid' and there should be one similar on each. I'm trying to find which one is missing on second table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
select userid from cw_users where userid not in(select userid from cw_users_data)
```

Comment: this is terribly inefficient

Answer (score 15):

Another method

```
SELECT cw_users.userid FROM cw_users
LEFT JOIN cw_users_data ON cw_users.userid=cw_users_data.userid
WHERE cw_users_data.userid IS NULL;
```

Comment: this is the most efficient answer

Comment: Very easy answer, I was not aware of `IS NULL` option.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
select userid from cw_users where userid not in (Select userid from cw_users_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select  userid from cw_users 
Except
Select userid from cw_users_data
```