# PHP array_diff VS mysql NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to compare two zipcode columns between two tables to see if values were missing in the second one.

I first wanted to do it with mysql, my query was something like

```
'SELECT code FROM t1 WHERE t1 NOT IN (select code FROM t2)'
```

But it was really slow so I tried another way :
I made two select, and then compared the results with `array_diff()`.

With mysql : few minutes, and sometimes crash

With PHP : less than 1 second.

Can someone explain these differences ?
Is my SQL query wrong ?

Comment: Checking which values are missing within a table (compared to another) can easily be done with a `LEFT` or `RIGHT` `JOIN` they are just made for actions like this.. alternatively take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733197/how-to-find-missing-value-between-two-mysql-tables

Comment: How large are your second table `t2` and do you have an index on the `code` column else try to add that and see what happens. My guess why it is so slow in mysql is because you actual don't have any index set. Try to run an `EXPLAIN` query from your terminal and see what keys are used ie `EXPLAIN SELECT code FROM t1 WHERE ta NOT IN ( SELECT code FROM t2 );`

Comment: Both tables have around 50 000 rows.
@serjoscha : This is a good idea. The example I used was found in multiple SO threads, so it seemed good

Comment: Okay, so your problem is solved? --------- One more thing: array_diff is not a good idea because: to use array diff, the **ENTIRE** data needs to be fetched from the SQL Server before you can determine differences. This is **NOT** a good way of performance programming. But when solving your Problem with mysql everything is processed on the server and only the result is sent back to you. In nearly all cases this is the **much much much** more quick way to implement your script

Comment: @Cyclone : You're right, I have no index. However, i don't understand the result of EXPLAIN

Comment: @FC - If you don't have an index you should definitly add one since this will speed up your query. You could add an index like this: `ALTER TABLE <table> ADD INDEX code_idx (code)` **this should be done for both tables**. If you then were to execute `EXPLAIN` for the query you would see something like `Using where; Using index; Using join buffer` which is **good**

Comment: @serjoscha : I should have said that this is a one time query, just to fill missing data. This is not a script that will be ran regularly.

Comment: @FC - You should read more about [Optimization and Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html)

Comment: well, then its not a big deal of course, but never the less solving the problem using SQL is way better for its elegant, quick and relatively easy. You could even formulate a INSERT directly from the result of the table diff-join. That would be awesome :) Further more: you could create a stored procedure from the query saved on the SQL server enabling to to easily run the script again in some time. This would prevent you from the need of searching the script you wrote now to do the work. Thats always a good thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your main table has 50k rows, using a **sub select** in your query will result into **1 + 50k executions** of selects. One for the first table, and 50k selects, one for each row. The server compares the row with your sub select that is reloaded every time iterating the main table. This is why your sql code takes its time and it also may be a huge memory problem as well.

See [serjoschas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3214501/serjoscha) information about **joins** to fix it in sql, it should be even faster that your php solution.

> Checking which values are missing within a table (compared to another) can easily be done with a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN they are just made for actions like this.. alternatively take a look at this: [How to Find Missing Value Between Two Mysql Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733197/how-to-find-missing-value-between-two-mysql-tables) –  serjoscha

One solution to:

```
SELECT code FROM t1
WHERE code NOT IN ( SELECT code FROM t2 )
```

will be:

```
SELECT t1.code 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2
ON t1.code = t2.code
WHERE t2.code is null
```

Have a try. Also have a look on **indexing** as [Cyclone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1047662/cyclone) suggests:

> If you don't have an index you should definitly add one since this will speed up your query. You could add an index like this: ALTER TABLE  ADD INDEX code_idx (code) this should be done for both tables. If you then were to execute EXPLAIN for the query you would see something like Using where; Using index; Using join buffer which is good –  Cyclone

**Indexing** speeds up your query. If the table only provides one column, searching an index table with the same content as the source table will be exactly the same and redundant. Otherwise I strongly **recommend indexing** the **code column of t2** which leads to a high increase of performance and less memory consumtion.

Comment: He would also need to use a table name in conjunction with the selected field ie `SELECT t1.code` since `code` is ambiguous in this case.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed up that and the Indexing part.

Comment: Thanks,  nice summary. Thanks also Cyclone and serjoscha